# " com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react" ERROR APPEARS

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

**When i tried to setup React navigation, i also installed react native gesture handler.**

I have added the all the required thinks as per the link below in Main Activity class.

> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Am getting these bugs:

```
\MainActivity.java:9: error: package com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react does not exist
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
                                         ^
D:\ReactNative\taskproject\android\app\src\main\java\com\taskproject\MainActivity.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
                           ^
  symbol: class RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView
2 errors
```

This there any work around ? AM banging my head for past 2 days. Or do i have to setup something in gradle.
I have linked the react react gesture but still it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please post the contents of the following files `app/build.gradle`, `settings.gradle`, `MainApplication.java` and your `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for responding. I got this working by adding subsequent dependencies to build.gradle.

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash i am also facing the same issue can you please provide the detailed answer here 
thanks,

Comment: @androido  When i ran react-native gesture handle --link, It does got added to build.gradle
I manually added the dependencies to build.gradle
Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i ran react-native gesture handle --link, It does got added to build.gradle

I manually added the dependencies to build.gradle

Comment: can you write the list of added dependecnies? simple copy paste will be enough, I hope.

Comment: you mean the list from package.json

Comment: to build graddle and probably to the json.

Currently I struggle to understand, why the monorepo project starts on iOs simulator and a web browser, and fails to start on Android simulator.

Answer (score 9):

I was copying mainapplication from old projects

My problem was this line:

```
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
```

was replaced by this:

```
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
```

Comment: This worked when upgrading from v1 to v2 of react-native-gesture-handler

Answer (score 3):

After follow the installation guide [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html), I needed to add:

On android\settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
```

and run "react-native start"

And, finally, I add on android/app/src... MainAplication.java

```
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
```

and

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        // Add additional packages you require here
        // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            ....
            new RNGestureHandlerPackage() <----- here
        );
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open terminal in your project directory and after executing below command rebuild the project. Thanks in advance...

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler

npx pod-install ios
```

Comment: It's not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your build.gradle(Module: app) file 
implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading gradle version to latest in `project/build.gradle` worked for me.

Below are the steps:

1. Open project -> build.gradle and update

> ```
> dependencies {    
>     classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.X") to latest version
> ```

2. Sync project in android studio.
3. Update `MainActivity` as suggested by [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) documentation.

> Add the following code to the body of MainActivity class:
>
> ```
> @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
> {  
>     super.onCreate(null); 
> }
> ```
>
> and make sure to add the following import statement at the top of this file below your package statement:
>
> ```
> import android.os.Bundle;
> ```

4  Run the app.

Comment: It's not worked for me. There's no reaction when I click

Answer (score 0):

Simply cleaning gradle helps

```bash
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important how it is being exported from babel.config.js file.

The correct format is

```
module.exports = {
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      plugins: [
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            alias: {
              '^_(.+)': './src/\\1',
            },
            extensions: ['.android.js', '.ios.js', '.js', '.json', '.native'],
          },
        ],
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
     ],
};
```

onCreate method must be changed to the following

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(null); 
}
```

Include import android.os.Bundle just after the package declaration.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler' in your index.js or App.js file

yarn start --reset-cache
```