# React Native : Error cannot find symbol com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage

Tags: react-native, npm, react-navigation

I know that many related problems already asked but still none of them worked.

Error :

```
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_firestore
:react-native-firebase_firestore package.json found at /home/username/StudioProjects/agl-admin/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore/package.json......

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/username/StudioProjects/agl-admin/android/app/src/main/java/com/agladmin/MainApplication.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
                                         ^
  symbol:   class RNGestureHandlerPackage
  location: package com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react
/home/username/StudioProjects/agl-admin/android/app/src/main/java/com/agladmin/MainApplication.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
      packages.add(new RNGestureHandlerPackage());
                       ^
  symbol: class RNGestureHandlerPackage
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
....
```

Most Matching Question : [" com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react" ERROR APPEARS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204879/com-swmansion-gesturehandler-react-error-appears)

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "agl-admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "expo": "~44.0.2",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

What I've :

In android\settings.gradle `include ':react-native....` these two where already there

In  `MainAplication.java` `import  com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;` already there
and `new RNGestureHandlerPackage() List` was not there so i added.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
./gradlew clean
```

and then reinstall all.

=============== UPDATE =================

I fixed it by React downgrading to `"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.3"`
and resting cache. T

Comment: You add **google-services.json** in your project because you used firebase so you need to add that file.

Comment: i think this isn't solution because gesture handle is required for navigation and there's no connection between firebase.

Comment: `"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.3"` works for me

Answer (score 1):

In the new version (RNGH 2) you have to remove `.react`, so it's just `import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage;`!

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure added you add `react-native-reanimated` plugin into **babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

Comment: module.exports = function(api) {   api.cache(true);   return {     presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']   }; }; like this

Comment: thanks for this but unfortunately doesn't work for me